# Configuration files in Silverlight

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, configuration

I am writing a plugin for [Seesmic Desktop 2](http://seesmic.com/sd2), and this being my first time using Silverlight, I have a question:

Writing Windows apps, we have the application configuration file e.g. MyApp.exe.config that is used to store config values, and for the web we have Web.config. For Silverlight, there doesn't seem to be the same thing. Ok, there's not quite the same incentive, as you have to unzip the .xap package to access it, but even so...

My issue is that I have data, e.g. JSON web service enpoint URIs that I feel uncomfortable embedding directly in code, as they would normally go in .config files. Is there any equivalent/way around this for SL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a [resource](http://www.mohamedibrahim.net/blog/2010/01/27/creating-and-using-silverlight-app-settings-webconfig-configuration-applicatioin-settings-to-change-wcf-service-address-after-deployment-servicereferencesclientconfig-servicereferences-clientconfig/) that seems to address the issue by creating a normal XML file, and then using custom functions to load configuration settings from (and to?) the file. Failing any better solution, I will have to do this.

Comment: SL ***cannot Access*** to file in server, isn't? Where is `XMLFileInYourRoot.Config` ? _build action = content_ and _copy to output directory = always_ ?

Answer (score 3):

Store all your configurations in your Web Application Configuration file, and at you page (which hosts the SL ) get all the configuration from you web.config, and pass to SL via SL's initial parameters.

For further help you visit this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverlightWebConfig.aspx

Comment: Although I could make a request to download a configuration file, because the plugin is run by the Silverlight out of browser launcher (with Seesmic), I'd prefer a client based solution. What I have done is used an XML config file which I've loaded and got some custom configuration classes as below. Thanks for your answer!